# first_or_create method with embeds_many association in mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I have `User` model which used for omni-auth authentication. I have set it up so that different providers (like facebook, google accounts ) can be used for signing in. If the email is already in the database while signing up using these providers ,user is signed into that account.

`class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :providers
  field :email,type: String, default: ""
 end`

`class Provider
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  field :uid, type: String
  embedded_in :user
end`

And I am using `from_omniauth` method to find user based on the auth info.

`def from_omniauth(auth)
      user=User.find_by(email: auth.info.email)
      return user if user
      where(:"providers.name" => auth.provider, :"provider.uid" => auth.uid ).first_or_create do |user|
        user.email = auth.info.email
        user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      end
    end`

But I am getting an error when it cant find a user and tries to create one.
`Mongoid::Errors::UnknownAttribute: 
message:
  Attempted to set a value for 'providers.name' which is not allowed on the model User.`

But why does it consider this as a dynamic field generation as I have already defined the associations. I tried `find_or_initialize` method also but same error.

Can someone help me figure it out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There's some magic going on here.

When you are invoking #first_or_create on the above criteria:

```ruby
where(:"providers.name" => auth.provider, :"provider.uid" => auth.uid ).first_or_create do |user|
  user.email = auth.info.email
  user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
end
```

This is actually getting de-sugared into something more like this:

```ruby
found_user_with_provider = where(:"providers.name" => auth.provider, :"provider.uid" => auth.uid ).first
if found_user_with_provider.nil?
    new_user = User.new
    new_user.set(:"providers.name", auth.provider)
    new_user.set(:"providers.uid", auth.uid)
    new_user.email = auth.info.email
    new_user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
else
    found_user_with_provider.email = auth.info.email
    found_user_with_provider.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
end
```

Notice the attempt to set the value of "provider.name" and "provider.uid" **as attributes on the user instance** - which isn't actually what you want, and is what Mongoid is complaining about.

You actually probably want something more like this:

```ruby
def from_omniauth(auth)
  user = User.find_by(email: auth.info.email)
  return user if user
  found_user_with_provider = where(:"providers.name" => auth.provider, :"provider.uid" => auth.uid ).first
  if found_user_with_provider
    found_user_with_provider.update_attributes!(
      :email => auth.info.email,
      :password => Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    )
    return found_user_with_provider
  end
  User.create!({
    :providers => [
       Provider.new({
          :name => auth.provider,
          :uid => auth.uid
       })
    ],
    :email => auth.info.email,
    :password => Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
  })
end
```

Of course there's still one more problem, and that's that you are setting a #password attribute on your user instance.  Make sure to add:

```ruby
field :password,type: String, default: ""
```

To your user model - otherwise you'll get the same complaint about dynamic fields as before - just this time about a different field.